# Is medium text datatype will occupy 16MB, if my record data is around 50KB

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using a `mediumtext` datatype for a column because it's needed in some rare cases.

But my doubt is if the record is 50KB size, then also `mediumtext` will occupy 16MB space or it will allocate only 50KB to that data?

Answer (score 3):

It will allocated ~50 KB. Just look to mysql manual at [blob datatypes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html).